# Merging two backbone collection and models into one object using underscore

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I have two backbone collections Categories and Items, Categories contains category models with id, name, and items (w/c contains item ids in string format separated by commas) and Items collection that contains item models(id, name, etc.).

How do I merge them into one object that can be easily be rendered in a handlebars template

**Sample Structure:**

```
var Categories = [{'id':'1', 'category_name':'Burgers', 'category_items':'1,2'},{'id':'2','category_name':'Drinks','category_items':'3'}];

var Items = [{'id':'1','item_name':'Burger 1'},{'id':'1','item_name':'Burger 2'},{'id':'1','item_name':'Chicken; 1'}];
```

**Sample Output:**

```
var output = [{'id':'1', 'category_name':'Burgers', 'items':[{'id':'1','item_name':'Burger1', ...},{'id':'1','item_name':'Burger2', ...} ]}, {'id':'2', 'category_name':'Chicken', 'items':[{'id':'3','item_name':'Chicken1', ...} ]
```

And yes, i tried enough, but I can't seem to manage it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on Underscore's helpful functions:

```
var json = _.map(c.toJSON(), function(c) {
  return _.extend(c, {
    category_items: _.map(c.category_items.split(','), function(id)                 {
      return i.get(id).toJSON();
    })
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/626x9/1/

The first `_.map` coupled with `_.extend` just serves the purpose on replacing the `category_items`. I find it quite abusive, but can't remember if there's any method that would do that in one shot.

Comment: wow, this is the code I needed with less lines of code, i know i can still optimize this but it is hard to explore and experiment with various underscore methods, my version uses `each`, then `get` then `push`, but i like this one better thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I write a function called "mergeObjectWithId". It merge data from two collection follow these step:

1. Using [collection.findWhere()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) to get the target model which need to merge.
2. Using [collection.where()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) to get the models in item collection.
3. Then assign the items array to target object's property items. Now you get the output object which you wanted.

Try this function:

```
function mergeObjectWithId(id){
  //assume categories is your Category collection instance
  var obj = categories.findWhere({id:id}).clone();
  //assume items is your Item collection instance
  obj.items = items.find({id:id}).slice(0);
  return obj;
}

var output = mergeObjectWithId(1);
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: thanks, i managed to create the same function but instead of using findWhere and or find i used get since it is a unique id in a collection.