# BackboneJS - how to merge multiple Models into one single model

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a way to merge multiple models into one single model?

I have several models, where I fetch a specific API which all have the same default values. So for later use, I was planning to do a single model which the collections can relate to but on of my issues is how to handle all the api's and how to include these into one single model.

A model in my app looks like:

```
function($, Backbone) {
 var CarModelD = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "../cars/index.php/api/d_cars/d",

    defaults: {
        "id": '',
        "fabricate": '',
        "carmodel": '',
        "year"
    }
});

return CarModelD;
}
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Do you mean `collection`?

Comment: @RoyMJ possibly!? Maybe I do need both?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314370/merging-two-backbone-collection-and-models-into-one-object-using-underscore and let me know if what you want is something like this ?

Comment: @RoyMJ Yeah, something like this... I asked a similiar question to this one before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427524/ to a different project, but its almost the same...